# Count number of parts in a MEF container

Tags: mef

I messed up in my code - I create lots of short-lifetime objects and use MEF to resolve dependencies. As anyone with some MEF experience knows, MEF holds onto a reference on these guys. The result is the short lifetime turns into LOOONNNGGG lifetime. So, this is easy enough to fix - use SatisfysImportsOnce on CompositionContainer.

But I'd like to make this x-check part of my unit tests now so that I don't accidently add an incorrect part into the container (or perhaps I missed one in the code search I just did). Sooo... how to do this?

My code, a bit abstracted, looks something like this:

```
        _catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        _container = new CompositionContainer(_catalog);
        _batch = new CompositionBatch();
```

I then add parts to a batch, and call _container.Compose(_batch). I thought perhaps something like the following would work to get a count, but it always returns zero:

```
        int nParts1 = _container.Parts.Count();
        int nParts2 = _container.Catalogs.Sum(c => c.Parts.Count());
```

However, both of those return zero. How can I get this count for tests? It is ok if perf isn't fantastic - this is part of the test, not the running app. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a simple way to do this.  You'll need to go digging around in the internal implementation of MEF to find this information.  Since the source code is available ([mef.codeplex.com](http://mef.codeplex.com)) this is quite possible, but still not too simple.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'd forgotten they were maintaining that. I will take a look at that. I guess the reason is isn't easy is b/c it has been abstracted away. I'll write back if I find anything.